# Multiply list of lists Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a function to multiply a list of lists (Matrix) in Haskell.

So far, I have been able to define a function to multiply two lists, though I'm not sure about list of lists. Could anyone lend a hand?

```
mult m1 m2 = zipWith (*) m1 m2
```

Comment: Exactly what would the output be? A new list of lists (matrix)?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Correct.

Comment: So you multiple *two* lists of lists, right?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Yes, two lists of lists. Sorry, missed that in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the same trick for each two rows of the matrix, so:

```
elementwiseMult :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
elementwiseMult = zipWith mult
```

with `mult` the function you defined to multiple two rows together.

Comment: I object to the name `matrixMult`, since multiplying corresponding elements of matrices is not matrix multiplication.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: yes, probably `elementwiseMult` is a better name.